# Is polymorphism in C# so polymorphic as could be?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, polymorphism, lambda

I wonder, how is C# polymorphic?

If we base on the definition of the word: **polymorphism** ( *...polymorphism in the context of object-oriented programming, is the ability to create a variable, a function, or an object that has more than one form...* ), of course I can provide more determinations of the polymorphism, but I think on the average with different words all of us understanding what is the polymorphism in Computer Science.

So, about my question, which I relate to C#.

For e.g., I'm using the very plain and simple example, here is a standard virtual method in one class `A` and the overriding method in other class `B`:

```
using System;


class A
{
    public virtual void CallMe(string incString)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(incString);
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void CallMe(string incString)
    {
        incString += "_new";
        Console.WriteLine(incString);
    }
}

class App
{
    static void Main()
    {
        B objectB = new B();
        objectB.CallMe("hello");
    }
}
```

First of all, I was upset: Why does C# now allow to use overriding of the both return type and the arguments of a method?

For e.g., just to set:

```
public override int CallMe(string incString)
```

But you won't get the fine result, you'll catch an compiler exception:

```
B.CallMe(string)': return type must be `void' to match overridden member
```

For the situation that I've described, we can only solve it in C# by hiding a method with using a keyword `new` if I want to define a method with a similar name, but different return type/list of arguments. I want to admit, that if we hide it, it's not a polymorphism at all,  it just a hiding process. Polymorphism in its definition requires to override the existed stuff (the similar process could be found in other scientific sciences like chemistry, maths etc...)

For e.g. maths allow to use the polymorphism of the 2nd, 3rd... N-arny order where the existed set or object could be always redefined. But what for the Computer Science and C# exactly?

I've read, but not try, that some functional programming languages (LISP, Haskell) do allow such features.

Is it possible see in C# in future, because as I see C# with each new version is increasing its functional stuff, more and more and maybe it will be possible with lambdas/delegates?

What do you think about it?

Comment: Kindly don't use code-highlighting for non-code, and use it sparingly. It breaks up text and makes it harder to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Polymorphic principles*

Many topics in Computer Science require a certain rigor. Polymorphism is not one of the exceptions. The requirement to share return types is an important one, and allows many time saving and powerful assumptions to be made. A method which does not have the same output is not polymorphic (that other languages abuse this process is probably why they don't get to use lambdas or some of the other nice inference features C# has).

As it stands, it is not possible to infer which method to call based on its return type because `The signature of a method does not include the return type.`

---

*Stick to best practice*

Writing readable code which employs true polymorphic principles is best.

You can see how the below process will become hard to read. A better way would be to **Separate Concerns** (another large topic in Comp Sci). What is really being done with this int, or with these return values. More than likely they represent a fork in logic and should probably be defined with different signatures to reflect that the logic is different for those cases.

---

*Compiler can't infer return type*

If you were to have two definitions which had the same signature but returned different types, there is no way to tell which one should be used, and the compiler will throw an error along the lines of "a member is already defined with the same parameter types".

Here is an example of why using different return types could be bad. Let us assume this compiles

```
public override string CallMe(string incString)
{
    incString += "_new";
    return incString;
}

public override int CallMe(string incString)
{
    incString += "_new";
return 1;
}
```

How would the compiler know which to use for situations of inference?

```
object o = CallMe("hello");
var v = CallMe("hello");
Type t = CallMe("hello").GetType();
```

---

*Generics can do this*

Generics are a powerful tool of C#. For your example, it is easy to solve using generics. However, this is going to require switching on types which is sometimes criticized.

```
class A{public virtual void CallMe(string incString){Console.WriteLine(incString);}}

class B : A
{
 public override void CallMe(string incString)
 {
    incString += "_new";
    Console.WriteLine(incString);
 }

 public T CallMe<T>(string incString)
 {
    CallMe(incString);
    object o;
    switch( typeof(T).ToString() ){
        case "System.String":
            o = incString;
            break;
        case "System.Int32":
            o = 1;
            break;
        default:
            o = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            break;
    }
    return (T)o;
 }
}
```

Which would be used like this:

```
static void Main()
{
 B objectB = new B();
 objectB.CallMe("hello");//writes "hello_new"
 int i = objectB.CallMe<int>("generic");//writes "generic_new"
 string s = objectB.CallMe<string>("world");//writes "world_new"
 A a = objectB.CallMe<A>("!");//writes "!_new"
 Console.WriteLine(i);//1
 Console.WriteLine(s);//"world"
 Console.WriteLine(a);//new A()
}
```

---

*Bottom line*

C# is very polymorphic, however it is important to avoid getting into code which is hard on everyone and to have a structured approach. Have unique signatures which are predictable so that more powerful assumptions can be made about what to expect.

Clearly this code has begun to have too many cross cutting concerns in that is has too many responsibilities and is in desperate need of a refactor.

In my opinion, C# is the best language to code in; and that is due in large part to the painstaking way it is designed with regards to enforcing best practice.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you're confusing *overriding* with *overloading*. Overriding is applicable, when you want to give different behavior for the method with the *same* signature.

Overloading, from the other hand, is a way to make method with the same *name*, but the different signature. I think, mixing these two concepts will be a hell.

> Is it possible see in C# in future

I hope, no, it won't be possible. At least because this will be a breaking change.

*UPD*.

Let's think, that what you want is possible. Look at these classes:

```
class A
{
    public virtual int CallMe(string incString)
    {
        // some code    
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void CallMe(string incString)
    {
        // some code
    }
}

// somewhere in the code (e.g., host application, which loads a plugin)
var a = serviceLocator.GetService<A>(); // indeed returns `B` instance 
var result = a.CallMe(); // hey, stop! B.CallMe is void. WTF?
```

How the code, which knows only about `A`, should behave, when instead of `A` at run-time it will receive `B`?

Comment: I don't think, that I'm confusing, because I even don't say a single word "overloading", because as I accustomed to word `overloading`, when I see such a word, I imagine the `event` overloading, of overloading some `UI`, but for the method signature I mean exactly overriding, because to save a concept of polymorphism , if we think about C# correct words, which relate to one or other meaning. If we take the meaning `overloading` globally not in C# only, then the overriding and overloading may be very close to each meanings, even maybe equal, don't think so?

Comment: No, I don't think so. First of all, we're limited by existing C# ideology and amount of code. They can't be just abandoned. The second, even if we will be abstracted from C# and .NET, contract breaking is a very, very bad idea. Updated the answer.

Comment: in yours updated answer, I don't understand why for the sample you preferred to use `GetService<A>`, of course if you launch the method with explicitly call with `A` class it will throw an exception by the abstract idea. I think, that in this situation the best variant is: `serviceLocator.GetService<B>()`, where by calling by default the type ob B, it will create the type of object you wanted by RTTI/reflection stuff, so I don't understand your UPD clearly, all runtime features could work with a RTTI in behind mechanism by loading some tables of types/classes an analyzing it at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a `virtual/abstract` method, you are defining a contract between a base class and all ist possible future derived classes. The derived classes need to "agree" to this contract by providing methods containing the exact signature as the `virtual/abstract` method implied.
How do you think will polymorphism work if you broke that very contract? It won't work at all!
Consider `interface`s that you can implement like `IEnumerable` to enumerate through a collection.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb.aspx)

It contains a method `bool MoveNext()`, if you could change the signature to anything you like, you would break the entire framework, because `foreach` could not rely on your objects to provide a legal `MoveNext()`-method.

Again from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

An override method provides a new implementation of a member that is inherited from a base class. The method that is overridden by an override declaration is known as the overridden base method. The overridden base method must have the same signature as the override method. For information about inheritance, see [Inheritance (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The point of polymorphism in object oriented programming, is that you can have different classes with methods that do different things, but you call them in the same way. Therefore overriding is done with the exact same method signature, because if you would change the signature, then you can't use the methods in the same way.

As the method signature stays the same, you can have code that uses a reference to the base class (or an interface), and an actual instance that can be any class that implements the type. The code can make the same calls without caring about what the actual type is.

Example:

```
A obj;
if (new Random().Next(2) == 0) {
  obj = new A();
} else {
  obj = new B();
}
obj.CallMe("hello");
```

Comment: interesting, but for e.g. LISP also supports OOP, but it could make full redefinition of the functions in the inheritable class with using `defun` macros in it (yes, it could be used for redefining too), so what? I think, that OOP is very different in different paradigms and different languages. Also I haven't read enough about supporting different types of morphism in OOP, like: `isomorphism`, etc

Comment: @OlegOrlov: In a language that is not strictly typed, you can change the signature somewhat as long as you still can use it the same way. If you change it so that you can't use it the same way, then it's not polymorphism any more, and it's equivalent to using the `new` keyword in C# to shadow the method.

Answer (score 1):

Rule-wise, your case is not that far-fetched, because conceptually, returning something instead of nothing will not break use cases... conceptually.

There are, however, several different factors at play. First, C# is programmed in such a way that, usually, the useful output of a method is given back as the return value. By using polymorphism to change a `void` to a `string`, as you suggested, you would coerce users of the base class into ignoring that it has a meaningful output, which would be a sign of bad design at best.

That said, this case is probably a little extreme and involves returning types of a different size (which could also cause technical issues that could only be fixed by making the whole language slower). There are milder implementations of that concept that could be put to use. It would be possible to have overrides accept a looser type, like `object` instead of `string`, or returning a more precise type, like `B` instead of `A` in your first example; that's called covariance and contravariance. These would not cause technical issues, as references are all the same size. I also believe that this is possible in Java, though I would need to check. I do know for a fact that it's possible in Objective-C for blocks that return or accept Objective-C types.

As far as I know, it hasn't made it to C# method overrides, probably because Microsoft decided that the cost of developing, testing and maintaining the feature outweighted the benefits.

As a side note, it has, however, made it to generic arguments. When you declare a generic type, it's possible to annotate the type with `out`, which means "this or a subclass". For instance, IEnumerable is defined as `IEnumerable<out T>`; this means that any `IEnumerable<string>` is also an `IEnumerable<object>`.